# The easiest way to pass data between application in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

What's the easiest way to pass data(string value) between two android applications with less or even without permissions? Also in my case first application sends data to un-existed application which is installing and it can't listen for intent right now.

Thanks.

Comment: Android answer is Parcelable and Intent.

Comment: will it save intent from A application for couple hours/days and when application B starts it will receive sent intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is tricky when you can't ensure that both applications are running.  In cases like that, you must rely on some form of persistent storage.

If you're concerned with only a small amount of data, Android provides a `SharedPreferences` [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to share preferences between applications.  Most notably, you can add a [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) to each application so they can be notified when the other changes the value.

You can find more information on various different forms of persistent storage on the [Android website (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Thanks, it seems the easiest way to emulate install_referrer intent which doesn't work on 3.1+

Comment: It seems that onle External Storage is available for multi-application access :(

Answer (score 1):

So as you are mentioning [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and extras put to it is the way to go.

If you want to let an application receive data even if it's still installing there is no straight-forward way.

One way is as follows:
In the `receiver`-part of your code, send a `received successfully`-extra to the `sender`-application. If the `sender`-application does not get the `received successfully`-message after some time, store the data and wait until the application is installed. you may store this data on sd-card and let the other application read that on first use.

you can also do a check if the application is installed with [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).